# Compatibility of two bi-dimensional measures

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics

As my last chance I try to post this question here, it seemed like a simple one but I have so much trouble finding an answer.

While doing the PET experiment, one needs to reconstruct the original position of the source of radiation which supposedly behaves like the patient. With some technique, from one measure we can find the x and y position of the source with their statistical and systematical error.
We can measure the "real" x and y position of the source with their casual errors therefore we want to test our reconstructed position with the real one.

In univariate analysis one would use something like a t-test, setting a confidence level $\alpha$ and computing the value of:

$t = \frac{|\hat{x}-x|}{\sqrt{\sigma_{\hat{x}}^2+\sigma_{x}^2}}$ then search ion tables if $t>t_{\alpha}$ and decide to reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis.

Is there some test for compatibility of two measures in the bi-variate case?

I found the Hotelling $T^2$ but it does not seem to take care of two measures but just compare the measure with a true value (which we do not have) correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks everyone!